# Given one div height sized to an image in a container, can flexbox automatically compute a second div height to fill the container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, calc

I'm hoping I can use flexbox to solve a div stacking problem.

I have one container div. Its height is `100vh`.

Inside that div, I have two divs.

One, contains an image. Its height is dependent on the size of image, which grows proportional to browser width up to a `max-width`.

A second div is on top of the first div. I want its `height` to be equal to the remaining height of the div.

Can flexbox compute this for me automatically? Hoping so.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/212/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. Try appying `flex: 1` to the second `div`. That tells it to stretch to fill the remaining space in the container.

Here's an illustration of the effect: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j83fj61h/)

Comment: That's addressed in the demo. Uncomment the `flex-direction: column` rule. [**Revised Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j83fj61h/1/)

Comment: Sorry, you did mention the vertical stacking in your question. That part escaped me when preparing the demo, where it was included as an alternative.